# Failure to use Service Principal to access Azure Resource Manager through Fluent .NET API

Tags: azure, f#, azure-active-directory

I can successfully log-in with the Service Principal through PowerShell and list the Resource groups using `Find-AzureRmResourceGroup`, so this is not a permissions issue.

It appears I can successfully authenticate the user with the .NET Fluent API, but on attempting to list Resource Groups, I get

```
Authentication error while acquiring token: 'get_user_name_failed: Failed to get user name'

Failed to get user name ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done
```

My F# source code:

```
open Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent
open Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent

//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/dotnet-sdk-azure-authenticate?view=azure-dotnet#mgmt-auth
let ClientId = "<Service Principal Application ID>"
let ServicePrincipalPassword = "<Service Principal Password>"
let AzureTenantId = "<tenant id goes here>"
let AzureSubscriptionId = "<subscriptionID>"

let azureCredentials =
    let userLoginInformation = Authentication.UserLoginInformation()
    userLoginInformation.ClientId <- ClientId
    userLoginInformation.Password <- ServicePrincipalPassword
    Authentication.AzureCredentials(userLoginInformation, AzureTenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)

let azure = Azure.Configure().Authenticate(azureCredentials).WithSubscription(AzureSubscriptionId)

//fails on execution of this line
let resourceGroups = azure.ResourceGroups.List() |> Seq.cast<IResourceGroup>
```

The full error and stack trace

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication error while acquiring token: 'get_user_name_failed: Failed to get user name'. ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalException: get_user_name_failed: Failed to get user name ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformSpecificHelper.GetUserPrincipalName()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler.<PreRunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.UserTokenProvider.<LoginSilentAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.UserTokenProvider.<LoginSilentAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.AzureCredentials.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperationsExtensions.<ListAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperationsExtensions.List(IResourceGroupsOperations operations, ODataQuery`1 odataQuery)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsImpl.List()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005.main@() in E:\GitRepos\AzureSandbox\src\AzureSandbox\Scripts\Script1.fsx:line 20
```

Comment: That `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` inner exception is throwing me for a loop.  Doesn't quite seem like that's what I'd expect there.

I know nothing about F#, but I'll install it real quick and see if I can repro this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it.  You're using `Authentication.UserLoginInformation()` when you want `Authentication.ServicePrincipalInformation()`.

I replaced the `let azureCredentials =` line with this, and it worked fine.

```
let azureCredentials =
  let servicePrincipalInformation = Authentication.ServicePrincipalLoginInformation()
  servicePrincipalInformation.ClientId <- ClientId
  servicePrincipalInformation.ClientSecret <- ServicePrincipalPassword
  Authentication.AzureCredentials(servicePrincipalInformation, AzureTenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
```

```